# Can rootca validity start date be lower than current date?

Tags: openssl, x.509

What will happen if we create rootca X509 certificate with validity date lower than current date? Will date of creation taken into account while cms_verify?

What will happen if we change the system time to a lower date but after the validity start date, why will the cms_verify fail?

```
    Validity
        Not Before: Apr  4 09:26:00 2016 GMT
        Not After : Apr  4 09:26:00 2026 GMT
```

faketime -f "2017-01-01 01:00:00" bash -l

date

So 1. Jan 01:00:00 IST 2017

openssl smime -verify -in a.cms -CAfile ./../data/CA.pem -out b.cms.xml

Verification failure

140392937076368:error:21075075:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:certificate verify error:pk7_smime.c:342:Verify error:certificate is not yet valid

Comment: Can you provide details of the testing you've done (especially since the question depends on environment things like modifying system clock). Do you have evidence that cms_verify _does_ fail?

Comment: Can you also post the root cert you created? What is its `Valid From:` field set to? Do you see any other dates in it?

Comment: @MikeOunsworth used faketime to change date . yes cms_verify fails using openssl smime -verify.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth It had single date 2016 ,set the current date to 2017 it fails.So I was thinking does date of creation matters.?

Comment: The only dates in a cert are the ones ... in the cert. I'm guessing your faketime isn't behaving the way you expect.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth faketime works fine ..checked with date ..verify ok after 2017 date set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A certificate has no record of when it was created, just the validity period, represented as a date (and time) for `notBefore` and `notAfter`; and either of them can be set to whatever you like (though there's not a well defined behavior of setting `notAfter` to a value less than `notBefore`, other than "not working").

Comment: any other possiblity of cms_verfiy to fail if we change current date to a value below today to notBefore date.If today is the creation of rootca crts.

Comment: 140392937076368:error:21075075:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:certificate verify error:pk7_smime.c:342:Verify error:certificate is not yet valid